# ¿Cómo colocar dato en columna secundaria postgresql?

Tags: postgresql

Me solicitaron llamar dos tablas, lo cual lo hice con un inner join, además realizar una columna secundaria llamada **`Limite`**, donde el **`salary`** si es mayor que **`max_salary`** debe llenarse la tupla de este con **`Excedido`**, lo cual no se como se implementa, solo me regresa un `false` o `true`, anexo mi código:

```
select e.first_name, 
       e.job_id, 
       e.salary, 
       j.max_salary, (e.salary > j.max_salary) as "Limite" 
from employees as e 
inner join jobs as j on (e.job_id = j.job_id);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes usar la clausula `CASE`, te pongo un seudo-codigo

```
select e.first_name, 
       e.job_id, 
       e.salary, 
       j.max_salary, 
        CASE
          WHEN (e.salary > j.max_salary) THEN Excedido
          ELSE 
           otro_valor_que_quieras
        END as "Limite" 
from employees as e 
inner join jobs as j on (e.job_id = j.job_id);
```